# Ban the "void" tag?

Tags: feature-request, spam, blacklist-request

We've been hit with some Russian spam recently.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/void

[image]

I've almost run out of the spam flags by now so maybe a quick idea - let's ban the [void] tag from being created? ;) Together with "you must use at least one tag when posting" it could slow them down a bit until we get more moderators or something...

Here's relevant link to Meta SO: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blacklist-request

Comment: You'd only stop them for a few minutes, then they'll change tags. If you properly nuke the posts with spam flags, the automatic filter should kick in soon (until the spammer adapts, no automatic filter is perfect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just spent a few minutes in the moderators' chat room. Apparently blacklisting doesn't help much with spammers - they'll just move on to another tag. I did notice that, for some reason, [there was one question with the 'void' tag](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14168/pagereference-return-null-vs-void), meaning that any new user could create a void-tagged post.

I just removed the tag from that question, so now the void tag will be deleted in the nightly batch job. [Only users with rep > 150 can create a tag](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), so, hopefully, this will stem the tide a bit.

Also, flagging questions as spam should get the originating IPs banned. I'll keep a watch for more spam...

Comment: If only it were possible to integrate flagging spam and minecraft somehow. :)